# How to override Custom Forms in Orchard CMS

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.7

I have enabled the Custom Forms module and added a new Custom Forms widget with the content type set as a custom content type. All works fine, however, I want to override the HTML generated.

I can see that the `\Modules\Orchard.CustomForms\Views\Items\Create.cshtml` is responsible for rendering the form. But how do I override this file?

I have tried creating a custom `\Themes\TheThemeMachine\Views\Orchard.CustomForms\Item\Create.cshtml` view but that doesn't work.

Comment: I'm using Orchard 1.7.2 btw

Comment: Are you trying to override the form template, or the field templates?

Comment: @justrhysism the form template, specifically, the submit button of the form. I have overridden the fields using `\EditorTemplates\Fields\Input.Edit.cshtml`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\Views\Orchard.CustomForms\Item\Create.cshtml` is correct for overriding a custom form item.

However if you are using a widget to render the custom form, as in my case, then you need to override `Parts.CustomForm.Wrapper.cshtml` in the `Views` folder of your theme.

[This post in the Orchard forums](https://orchard.codeplex.com/discussions/536714) gave me the answer.